Google Drive for Desktop – How to stop the "Syncing files from local folders to Computers" on my Mac?
I am using a MacBook with OS macOS Big Sur version 11.7.10. I am also using the application Drive for Desktop on the same device.
Some context before I ask my question: On the homepage for Drive for Web (i.e., https://drive.google.com/drive/home), I see three things, namely My Drive, Shared drives and Computers. Please see Picture 3.
Inside Computers I see my laptop My MacBook Pro, and inside that, there are the two folders which I have chosen to sync with Google Drive. Please see Picture 1. (These two folders are Folder C and Folder D in the structure below).

Drive for Web - Home (https://drive.google.com/drive/home)

My Drive

Folder A


Shared drives

Folder B


Computers

My MacBook Pro

Folder C (Aetna)
Folder D (Career & Jobs - MS)







I am using Stream files as my Drive syncing options. Please see Picture 2.
Also, this version of macOS uses Alternative streaming method (it does not use File Provider).
Now, I would like to stop the synchronizing of those two folders with Google Drive (Folders C and D), and, after that, I would like to disconnect my account from Google Drive so that I no longer continue with the synchronizing.
My question: How do I stop the synchronizing while not losing any files inside those two folders (Folders C and D)? In the picture attached, there is no option called stop sync or anything similar. There is one option to Disconnect account directly (see Picture 4) but there is no option to simply stop syncing before doing that.
So I am worried that I may lose all my files if I do that directly.
Can somebody please guide me on how to do this step-by-step?
Picture 1:



Picture 2:



Picture 3:



Picture 4:



Thank you in advance!

Just copy everything from those folders to other non-linked folders then close or remove the share. Did this with Dropbox.
